# where to keep an opened can of condensed milk safe

Tags: food-safety, evaporated-milk

Where is the best place to keep an opened can of condensed milk safe? I know the unopened one is okay on the counter but what about when you open the can to use half of it?

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep it in the fridge. This is generally true of any open can or jar. Once the seal is broken, you have to refrigerate as with any other non-conserved food.

Personally, I also refill it in a glass container, because sometimes the oxidizing metal of the can gives food an off taste.

Comment: +1 for glass!  Don't keep stuff in the metal tin: http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/07/why-you-shouldnt-store-open-tins-in-the-fridge/